# NSURLConnection didFailWithError connectionDidFinishLoading called at same time?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

Regarding "`didFailWithError`" and "`connectionDidFinishLoading`"

Can they both be called? Or its always one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they cannot be called at the same time.

After the delegate receives a message `connection:didFailWithError:`, it receives no further delegate messages for the specified connection.

If the connection succeeds in downloading the request, the delegate receives the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` message. The delegate will receive no further messages for the connection and the `NSURLConnection` object can be released.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 3):

While not obvious, the docs make a statement that only one of these two will be called. It either finishes successfully and **connectionDidFinishLoading** is called, or it fails with an error and **didFailWithError** is called. You can find this in the **NSURLConnectionDataDelegate docs for the **connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:** method.

Edit: It looks like the answer from @erkanyildiz shows the better info from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

From docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

connectionDidFinishLoading:

> Sent when a connection has finished loading successfully.

**Successfully**. Seems like always one or the other.